# MFC VC++: How to remove blank space between the Window caption and Client area

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, ribbon

I am developing a desktop app using MFC. The following image shows the current state of the app's window top part. The area marked in red is unnecessary and I want to remove it.

How can I remove that space or atleast change the color to match the rest of the window background?

**More Info:**
The App is using Ribbon UI. I have added the App button programmatically in `onCreate` of `CMainFrame`. Is it the bar that holds the Ribbon categories? I tried SetMenubarState(AFX_MVS_HIDDEN) thinking it was the menu bar, but that didn't work. Just changing its color is also acceptable.

[image]

**Update:**
I have managed to change the color of that ribbon strip, and removed the caption bar I used for showing the 'add' button. Now I need to figure out how to place the 'Add' button on the right side of the ribbon strip.

Comment: What objects did you define in your mainframe. Seams that this is a caption that isn't used by you.

Comment: @xMRi The gray bar right below the blue bar is the `CMFCCaptionBar` with a button on the far right side.

Comment: In other words: Why do you create the caption bar?

Comment: @xMRi I have added the full window width image. I need a 'Add' button at the right side. I do not want to override the NCPaint method, easiest way was to add a bar with the button on it.

Comment: @xMRi I have managed to change the color of that ribbon background by overriding the `OnFillBarBackground` method of `CMFCVisualManager` and setting it as `CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager` for my app. Now I need to place the Add button on the ribbon's right side

Comment: "The area marked in red"? Maybe I am color-blind, but I do not see a red area in your image.